Task on Board - Azure Devops
Azure devops, is it possible to view stories and their tasks similar to what you have when you go to Sprint and taskboard but do it from the Board?
Want to see the tasks on the board without having to go to the sprint and see the taskboard?

Hi @Miguel Angulo Jara, have you checked my latest update. Feel free to let me know if you have any question.

Click Configure team settings in Boards.

Go to Annotations -> Enable Task -> Save and close.

Then you can see the tasks from Boards. Click the Task icon to expand the related tasks.


Can I have a Taskboard view, PBI pinned and its side tasks with their columns?

You can see PBI and its associate tasks in Boards following the above steps. But the state of the task isn't visible directly. Azure Boards provide a comprehensive view of your project’s work items, Taskboards offer a more focused view of tasks for a specific sprint or iteration. They are designed for different scenarios. If you want to view the state of a task, it is recommended that you view it from the Taskboard view. Or you can create a query to get your target tasks and add State column to the query result.
